# Module not Found after commenting function in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getstaticprops

Could someone explain what is going. I have been trying to follow this tutorial
https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/implement-getstaticprops
I'm currently having issues with getStaticProps to work aso I started poking around and when i
comment out getSortedPostsData(); or make it a string the getSortedPostsData module should be unused and I would have thought produce no errors however I get an error of cannot import fs from 'fs' which exists as an import within getSortedPostsData, why does this error occur?

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { getSortedPostsData } from '../lib/posts';
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';
export async function getStaticProps() {
  console.log("get static props runs")
  const allPostsData = 'getSortedPostsData();'
  return {
    props: {
      allPostsData,
    },
  };
}


export default function Home({ allPostsData }) {
  return (
    <Layout home>
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Read <Link href="/posts/first-post">this page!</Link>
        </h1>

        <p className={styles.description}>
          Get started by editing <code>pages/index.js</code>
        </p>

        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <a href="https://nextjs.org/docs" className={styles.card}>
            <h3>Documentation &rarr;</h3>
            <p>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</p>
          </a>

          <a href="https://nextjs.org/learn" className={styles.card}>
            <h3>Learn &rarr;</h3>
            <p>Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with quizzes!</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/master/examples"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h3>Examples &rarr;</h3>
            <p>Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js projects.</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://vercel.com/import?filter=next.js&utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h3>Deploy &rarr;</h3>
            <p>
              Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a public URL with Vercel.
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer>
        <a
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{' '}
          <img src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel" className={styles.logo} />
        </a>
      </footer>

      <style jsx>{`
        main {
          padding: 5rem 0;
          flex: 1;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }
        footer {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
          border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }
        footer img {
          margin-left: 0.5rem;
        }
        footer a {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          color: inherit;
        }
        code {
          background: #fafafa;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 0.75rem;
          font-size: 1.1rem;
          font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono,
            DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace;
        }
      `}</style>

      <style jsx global>{`
        html,
        body {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto,
            Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue,
            sans-serif;
        }
        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
    <section className={`${utilStyles.headingMd} ${utilStyles.padding1px}`}>
        <h2 className={utilStyles.headingLg}>Blog</h2>
        <ul className={utilStyles.list}>
          {/* {allPostsData
          .map(({ id, date, title }) => (
            <li className={utilStyles.listItem} key={id}>
              {title}
              <br />
              {id}
              <br />
              {date}
            </li>
          ))} */}
          {console.log(`info: ${allPostsData}`)}
        </ul>`your text`
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

I was expecting no error to occur when this is commented out and the module is not used.

Comment: You have a tagged template literal outside the commented code, so it makes the console.log function call with argument of `allPostsData` which results in your `getStaticProps` function getting called.